# How do I set a fallback redirect for a dynamic route in Next.js?

Tags: redirect, next.js, url-routing

I have a nested, dynamic route for my blog using this folder structure:

```
/pages
  /articles
    /page
    /[...page].js
```

This results in URLs like:

```
mysite.com/articles/page/1
mysite.com/articles/page/2
```

If someone types one of these URLs:

```
mysite.com/articles
mysite.com/articles/page
```

...I'd like to redirect them to `mysite.com/articles/page/1`.

How do I do that?

I'm thinking I could create:

```
/pages
  articles.js
  /articles
    page.js
```

Then, in these files, I could use the router...

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const router = useRouter();

router.push('/articles/page/1');
```

Having a new file for each fallback seems a little overkill though. Should I use the `_middleware.js` file instead?

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server'
export async function middleware(req, ev) {
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl
  if (pathname === '/articles' || pathname === '/articles/page') {
    return NextResponse.redirect('/articles/page/1')
  }
  return NextResponse.next()
}
```

I also see that redirects can be setup in `next.config.js`, but I get the impression that is more for 301 redirects.

Comment: Are you saying you don’t want it to be a permanent redirect? Another option would be to configure rewrite rules https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites